# More than one file was found with OS independent path 'lib/x86/libflutter.so'

Tags: flutter

**After I updated my flutter I got the following error while building my flutter app**

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug'.

  > More than one file was found with OS independent path 'lib/x86/libflutter.so'
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Comment: I tried invalidating the cache and flutter clean. This did not solve the problem.

Comment: I tried changing the channel from "master" to "stable" and that solved the above issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. Try to add the following in the gradle file

```
android {
  defaultConfig {
    ...
    packagingOptions {
        pickFirst 'lib/x86/libflutter.so'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I just changed my flutter channel to stable as mentioned in this link https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/sdk/upgrading

Comment: I had the same problem yesterday. Currently i'm working with the master channel and switching to stable did not resolved my problem. But adding the above code in the gradle file did. So that's why i left this answer here.
Maybe this will be a help for somebody :)

Comment: Yes. Thanks for your reply Mondok Tamas.